# JavaScript does not validate textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, authentication

As in the title , I made a login page in asp.net and want to check login and password checkbox . If textbox's will be empty , alert should popup , but nothing happens.

Code of JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function log() {
            var x = document.getElementById("tb_login").value;
            if (x == null || x.trim() == "") {
                alert("please type login");
                return false;
            }
            var z = document.getElementById("tb_pwd").value;
            if (z == null || z.trim() == "") {
                alert("please type pass");
                return false;

            }
        }
    </script>
```

And asp login page code :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage2.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {}
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <p>
        <br />
    </p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    ;<asp:TextBox ID="tb_login" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_pwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Overline="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <p>
   <asp:Button ID="btn_login" runat="server" OnClick="btn_login_Click" Text="Log In" OnClientClick="return log();" />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Register.aspx">Register new account !</asp:HyperLink>
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Your javascript code seems to be correct, check [javascript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for any errors, from what is seems, `btn_login_Click` isn't defined, which probably throws an error on click, hence preventing your `log()` function from executing.

Comment: btn_login_Click is definied . After click it check if user is register in db and if password is correct

Comment: Have you checked console for errors?

Comment: no errors on console

Comment: Just to prove it, javascript is correct: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/aboLxjss/). I don't know enough asp.net webforms to help with server side code. Some tips on what to check first: click the button and check for errors in console: if there is an error, the script is not included correctly and `log` function isn't accessible. If there is no error, check if your asp code compiles to something similar to my jsfiddle example, the important part is that `id="..."` attributes match. If none of this works for you, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: sorry , it throws this : method getPreventDefault() is obsolete

Comment: This is probably a warning, not an error. And you're not using anything like that in your code, that's asp's auto-generated code. Read my previous comment, I hope it will help, if not then good luck.

Comment: Make sure you didn't accidentally check "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" if asked. Try a different browser. Also rename log() to something more unique or better yet, namespace it. Maybe other scripts that are loading clobber that function with a naming conflict.